# Post files in list of ASP.NET MVC objects

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 site using Entity Framework where each item submitted in form has several fields, where one of which is supposed to be an uploaded Excel spreadsheet that is to be saved in the database. Here is what the data model looks like.

```
public partial class CostBreakdown
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    [StringLength(10)]
    public string CUSTOMER_ID { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [StringLength(6)]
    public DateTime BILLING_DATE { get; set; }

    public decimal TOTAL_COSTS { get; set; }

    public byte[] DOCUMENT { get; set; }  //The Excel document
}
```

Since files in ASP.NET MVC actions are posted as an HttpPostedFileBase object, I made a view model to try to bind everything to the view.

```
public class CostsVM
{
    public int TransactionFlag { get; set; }    //Used for update tracking

    public CostBreakdown Cost { get; set; }

    public HttpPostedFileBase UploadedFile { get; set; }
}
```

Since users would need several files at once, it is a List that is bound to the view. I did this in the loop of the view file to try to bind the files to several HTML file controls. This was based on an example that I found on another page (that I'm unfortunately having trouble going back and finding).

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
{
    @* All my other fields are bound here *@
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model[i].UploadedFile, new { type = "file", accept = ".xlsx", @class = "fileBox", id = "[" + i + "].UploadedFile" })
}
```

Ultimately, the file would be converted to a byte[] by the controller. However, the the values that I get back for the UploadedFile variables are always null. Is there a way that I could allow multiple rows of data to be bound, each with a file control and each allowing the user to upload a file that would be saved to the database for that record?

Answer (score 0):

So, this was my own doing. I had everything right with the method that I was trying, however I was attempting to do this in a call to Ajax.BeginForm, which doesn't accept files. Once I changed this to Html.BeginForm, it worked.